# When can I use the new keyword?

Tags: c#

I am starting to learn c#, but i don't know when to use `new` keyword, and when not to use it. generally i know why to use it, but as i am looking at some code on the internet, i can see that many times `new` keyword is not used - and those are places when i would use it.

example:

```
static void FileInfoClass()
{
    //this usage of new keyword i understand.
    FileInfo somefile = new FileInfo("c:\\test.txt");

    if (!somefile.Exists)
    {
        //this is the place where i would like to use new
        //like FileStream somefileStream = new FileStream();

        FileStream somefileStream = somefile.Create();                
        somefileStream.Close();
        somefile = new FileInfo("c:\\test.txt");
    }


    //same like before
    StreamWriter texttoAdd;            
    texttoAdd = somefile.CreateText();

    texttoAdd.WriteLine("This is a line in the file");
    texttoAdd.Flush();
    texttoAdd.Close();
}
```

this is the simplest example i can think of.

Comment: so what is a question ? where is the code that makes you warry?

Comment: You should read about the difference between constructors and methods as well as about return types.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @user - can u tell me what result you are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question this way: you know that `new` can be used to create an object, so you don't understand why is it not used for every case where a new object "appears" in your code.

Therefore, you want to know what is different in these two lines:

```
FileInfo somefile = new FileInfo("c:\\test.txt");
```

and

```
FileStream somefileStream = somefile.Create();
```

Well, the second one is not a direct construction of the object. Actually this command by itself does not create an object, it just calls a function that returns an object.

Given that the function is called "Create()", we can guess this function will create an object and return it (or will call another function that create an object and return it). But this is only a convention. Nothing in the language says that function called "Create()" should really create objects.

So when you use this function, your code is not the one responsible to create the object and therefore you don't use the keyword `new`. This pattern is called a [**Factory method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: thank you... i think this will clear many things now... tell me, is there a way when i can choose when to use factory method, or "factory way" ?

Comment: There is only one way to know what you should do: you should learn and understand the API. The documentation of the API should make clear how to use it and what you can expect from each factory method. In your example this the simpler way to obtain a FileStream corresponding to an already created File object. For a beginner, it is sometimes difficult to apprehend all the ways an API can be used, but with experience it will get simpler.

Comment: when you are saying learn API, in this case your are talking about MSDN documentaion for information finding?

Comment: Yes, I mean the MSDN documentation for the stuff you intend to use.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the new keyword can be used as an operator or as a modifier.

- [`new Operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - Used to create objects and invoke constructors.
- [`new Modifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - Used to hide an inherited member from a base class member.
- [`new Constraint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - Used to restrict types that might be used as arguments for a type parameter in a generic declaration.

---

**`new Operator`**

```
// cs_operator_new.cs
// The new operator
using System;
class NewTest 
{
   struct MyStruct 
   {
      public int x;
      public int y;
      public MyStruct (int x, int y) 
      {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
      }
   }

   class MyClass 
   {
      public string name;
      public int id;

      public MyClass () 
      {
      }

      public MyClass (int id, string name) 
      {
         this.id = id;
         this.name = name;
      } 
   }

   public static void Main() 
   {
      // Create objects using default constructors:
      MyStruct Location1 = new MyStruct();
      MyClass Employee1 = new MyClass();

      // Display values:
      Console.WriteLine("Default values:");
      Console.WriteLine("   Struct members: {0}, {1}", 
         Location1.x, Location1.y);
      Console.WriteLine("   Class members: {0}, {1}", 
         Employee1.name, Employee1.id);

      // Create objects using parameterized constructors::
      MyStruct Location2 = new MyStruct(10, 20);
      MyClass Employee2 = new MyClass(1234, "John Martin Smith");

      // Display values:
      Console.WriteLine("Assigned values:");
      Console.WriteLine("   Struct members: {0}, {1}", 
         Location2.x, Location2.y);
      Console.WriteLine("   Class members: {0}, {1}", 
         Employee2.name, Employee2.id);
   }
}
```

Output :

```
Default values:
   Struct members: 0, 0
   Class members: , 0
Assigned values:
   Struct members: 10, 20
   Class members: John Martin Smith, 1234
```

---

Source & Reference : [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: `new` has nothing to do with the heap.

Comment: @svick - read this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Why do you think only the oldest version of that document says that? All newer versions don't mention heap, because it's not accurate.

Comment: See the [VS2012 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4(v=vs.110).aspx) not the VS2003 documenation

Comment: @AppDeveloper So you think: `int i = new int();` allocates space on the heap?  It does not.

Comment: @Servy - i am not a coder who has read much book, all i know is c# allocates it somewhere!

Comment: @Servy - i was just tryin to find n paste answer thats it!

Comment: That's why understanding the answer to the question you're trying to write an answer for helps.  When you can only blindly copy the content of others you run the risk of copying incorrect content.

Comment: @Servy - dont do that generally, i read n understand, but since it was MSDN it was very much sure, and forgot to check it was older version of the documentation!

Comment: this is nice and thank you for your effort. but i am afraid, this is not an answer to my question.i understand this is general new keyword usage,and i am more or less good with it. the problem is, why the designer didnt make a new object for the StreamWriter, but instead he used FileInfo obj?

Comment: @user2026884 - how does designer comes into play?

Comment: @appdeveloper designer, programmer, developer ..... never mind

Comment: @user2026884 if you want to know why one way was chosen over another, that is a question for the person/team that wrote the code.

Comment: @JGinSD so you are telling me, that they can also use new with FileStream and StreamWriter?

Comment: @JGinSD sorry i didnt realized its your answer, and i wanted "second opinion"...ty....

Answer (score 0):

The new keyword is used to create a new object.

```
var someUser = new User();
```

For example, you use the new keyword when you want to create a new instance of a User.

Once you have the object (User is this case) then you can call methods on the object

```
someUser.UpgradeToPremiumAccount();
```

In the code you are looking at, they are creating a new FileInfo object and then calling the Exists method on that object.

For the StreamWriter, they are declaring a variable named texttoAdd, but they are not creating a new object.  The someFile.CreateText(); method is creating the object and returning it and it is being stored in the texttoAdd variable.

Comment: ok. i know that, thats not a problem. the simplest problem is illustrated in the code above. why the new keyword is not used like FileStream somefileStream = new FileStream();? any special reason or it could be used but......

Comment: thank you for your effort. see, i understand what the code is doing, what i dont understand is, i will take your example from the code for the StreamWriter, why they didnt make new object for the StreamWriter? how to choose when to make new object ( maybe this was the better question).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this comes down to what makes more sense and which classes should know about each other.

Imagine you're the one who is designing the `FileInfo` and `StreamWriter` classes. Now you need to add some way for the users to create `StreamWriter` from `FileInfo`.

You could decide to add new constructor to `StreamWriter` that takes a `FileInfo`:

```
public StreamWriter(FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    // some implementation, not important for us
}
```

Or you could add a method to `FileInfo` that creates the `StreamWriter` using some constructor that already exists:

```
public StreamWriter CreateText()
{
    return new StreamWriter(this.FullPath);
}
```

Both of them will work. So, now it's up to you as a designer to decide which option is better. Should `StreamWriter` know about `FileInfo` and accept it as a constructor parameter? The actual designers decided that no, `StreamWriter` should work with file names, but not `FileInfo`s. So they added `CreateText()` method to `FileInfo`.

In both cases, the `StreamWriter` object is ultimately created using `new`, but it may be hidden inside some method that knows how to properly create it.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `FileStream somefileStream = somefile.Create();` you don't need to use the `new` keyword here because inside the `Create` function call the `new` keyword is being used to instantiate the `FileStream`.  You only need to use `new` when you are directly calling an objects constructor.

You could create the `FileStream` manually by calling [`FileStream somefileStream = new FileStream(...);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.filestream.aspx).  This is case where there are many different ways you could create a `FileStream`.  There is even [`File.Open(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx).

Many objects in .NET have multiple ways in which you can instantiate them.

Whichever you use is entirely up to you.

Comment: so, this is connected with one of the answers before- factory method. its good to use it because removes duplication of code. thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: @user2026884 yes it is related to the answer that mentioned the factory pattern and svick's answer.

Answer (score -1):

The new keyword is only used to allocate memory to an object. In your case you already allocated memory to someFile. Now you are just returning a file object from create file to point someFile to. Like noted in the comments you need to read on return types, memory creation/object allocation.

Comment: What about constructors?

Comment: @svick when you are calling a constructor you are creating a new object and allocating the memory for it. So it is safe to saw when ever you call 'new' you are allocating memory for an object

Comment: But you said that `new` *only* allocates memory. That implies it *doesn't* call a constructor.

Comment: @svick I said the 'new keyword is only used to allocate memory to an object' NOT the new keyword only allocates memory to an object. I was stating what it is used for NOT what it can/cant do.